# Language parsing in Clojure with line numbers

Tags: parsing, clojure, parse-ez

I have a very simply language. A function is defined as some number of comments (indicated by the line starting with a semicolon) followed by a function name (a word followed by parens), followed by anything else, and ending with a "q". Here is a parse-ez function:

```
(defn routine []
 (multi* (regex #";.*")
 (regex #"(\w+)\(.*\).*" 1)
 (multi* (regex #"[^q].*"))
 (regex #"q.*"))
```

This works, but I want to return the line numbers on which the different patterns match. Is there a way to do this or do I need to write my own parser?

As it stands right now my language is simple enough that writing a new parser wouldn't matter too much, but it will limit me as complexity increases.

Comment: Is your goal to write a new language or to learn how to write a parser? If it's the former, than you can use one of several libraries listed here: http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/  If your goal is to learn *how* to write a parser, than just go for it.

Comment: @noahz: I just want to use a parser, no interest in writing one. Do you know if any of the parsers listed there support line numbers? It didn't seem to me like any did.

Comment: [parsley](https://github.com/cgrand/parsley) and [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) are two parsing libraries. They both have an issue created ([insta](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse/issues/8), [parsley](https://github.com/cgrand/parsley/issues/4)) requesting for line and column metadata for the parsed results.

The only one of these two libraries I've used is **parsely**, which actually keeps all the original text in the parsed result, so you could go through the parse tree looking for `\n` and calculating the line and column for each symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "line-pos" function in parse-ez. Can't you use that?

line-pos doc:

> "Returns [line column] vector representing the current cursor position
>   of the parser"